# XPath : Find following siblings that don't follow an order pattern

Tags: xpath, axes

This is for C code detection. I'm trying to flag case statements that don't have a break. The hierarchy of the tree looks like this when there are multiple lines before the break statement. This is an example in C:

```
switch (x) {
  case 1:
    if (...) {...}
    int y = 0;
    for (...) {...}
    break;
  case 2:
```

It is somehow represented as this:

```
<switch>
  <case>...</case>
  <if>...</if>
  <expression>...</expression>
  <for>...</for>
  <break>...</break>
  <case>...</case>
</switch>
```

I need to find `<case>`s where a `<break>` exists after any number of lines, but before the next `<case>`.

This code only helps me find those where the break doesn't immediately follow the case:

```
//case [name(following-sibling::*[1]) != 'break']
```

..but when I try to use following-sibling::* it will find a break, but not necessarily before the next case.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you use XPath 2.0 or are you stuck with 1.0? Also, your first paragraph says you're looking for case statements that *don't* have a break; your 3rd paragraph says you're looking for those that *do*. It may amount to almost the same thing, but clarity will help.

Comment: Good spot @LarsH, I updated my answer to reflect the limitation.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I tried to start by finding the break, thinking that I would just add a NOT to the statement to find those that didn't have the break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select any `case` that has a following `break` *and* either no following `case` or where the position of the next `break` is less than the position of the next `case`. With the positions determined by running `count()` on the preceding siblings.

```
//case
[
    following-sibling::break and
    (
        not(following-sibling::case) or
        (
            count(following-sibling::break[1]/preceding-sibling::*) <
            count(following-sibling::case[1]/preceding-sibling::*)
        )
    )
]
```

---

To grab the *other* cases, those without breaks, just throw a big old `not()` in there like so:

```
//case
[not(
    following-sibling::break and
    (
        not(following-sibling::case) or
        (
            count(following-sibling::break[1]/preceding-sibling::*) <
            count(following-sibling::case[1]/preceding-sibling::*)
        )
    )
)]
```

Comment: Thanks derp, I didn't think to compare the position of the break relative to the next case. This helped me solve my problem!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are struggling because your XML format does not really model the problem very well. It would be much easier if the other statements were nested inside the `<case>` elements, instead of being siblings, then you could just use `switch/case[break]`.

With your current structure, it's easiest to start by finding the `<break>` and then work backwards to find the matching `<case>`. As @LarsH pointed out, my original expression would find some additional clauses. It can't really be modified to fix that, unless you restrict it to find just the first case:

```
 switch/break/preceding-sibling::case[1]
```

@derp's answer is better, and can find both cases with and without breaks.

Comment: In general, this XPath expression could yield both case statements that do have a break, and those that don't (but are followed by another case that does have a break).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @PeterHall, It would be better to restructure the XML into something more closely representing the abstract syntax tree of the C grammar. You can do this easily enough (for this case) with XSLT grouping:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="case">
  <case>
    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[not(self::case)]"/>
  </case>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

You can then find cases with no break as `switch/case[not(break)]`.

Answer (score 0):

Derp's answer is correct. But I'll just add another. This selects case elements that do have a break:

```
//case[generate-id(.) =
       generate-id(following-sibling::break[1]/preceding-sibling::case[1])]
```

In otherwords, this selects case elements for which this is true:
The context element is identical to the first case element preceding the next break element (considering siblings only).

If you have a lot of case statements, this variant could be faster than using `count()`. But you never know for sure unless you test it with the relevant data using the relevant XPath processor.

BTW, the `.` in `generate-id(.)` is not required, as the argument defaults to `.` anyway. But I prefer to make it explicit, for readability.